# Can I make a backup of a single partition in a dual boot system, and restore that later?

Tags: linux, windows-10, partitioning, multi-boot

I am running a dual boot Windows 10/Linux Mint 18 on my Lenovo Thinkpad 13.

Last week I tried to siphon off some of the free space in the Windows partition to make a new partition to store some data using GParted, but it didn't end up working properly and the Windows installation died and now it won't boot into Windows (Mint is fine). I have tried many different ways to try and fix it, but I think I am just going to have to do a clean install of windows again, which is fine, as I don't really use windows except for some games and to print things off because my printer won't talk to Linux for some reason.

Here is what my partition table looks like in GParted:

[image: partition table]

You can see that the Windows partition (/dev/sda3) is just before the Linux partition (/dev/sda5) - for some reason, /dev/sda4 is at the end, I don't know why, but it probably has something to do with why its not working any more.

I have 3 questions about my situation:

Firstly, can I just delete the 3 windows partitions (/dev/sda2, /dev/sda3, /dev/sda4) and move /dev/sda5 to the start of the disk (after /dev/sda1) without damaging everything?

Secondly, if i do a clean installation of windows 10, can i tell it to just overwrite /dev/sda3 and leave everything else? or will it have trouble formatting that part of the disk and then installing there, because the linux partition is after it?

Lastly, before I do a clean install of windows, I am paranoid that the installation will ruin my Linux partition somehow (either wipe it completely, or just damage it so that I cannot run it). I am mid-way through my PhD and I have 3 years worth of work and installed packages that I can't afford to lose, so backing up everything is a much bigger task than just copying my files to an external hard drive. So before I do anything about installing Windows, I would like to back up my Linux partition with all of its installed programs and everything. If I was to use clonezilla or something to clone /dev/sda5 to another hard drive, and something *did* go wrong with the Windows install, would I be able to just wipe everything and restore /dev/sda5 to a clean hard drive and carry on? What about the system partition and stuff?

Sorry if these questions are too basic, I don't really know what I am doing when it comes to this low-level disk manipulation stuff, and I am really scared of losing everything.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and let me know if you need any other information that I may have left out.

Thanks

Comment: Has the Windows partition been lost, or only the boot files? If the latter, try a repair first; then try to install over the existing installation while preserving files (I have done this several times with upgrades). I would back up the whole disc, as restoring this gets back your current state immediately. I assume that you maintain at least two independent back-ups of your vital work files on separate media. If you're using CloneZilla, I recommend you boot the live disc.

Comment: Its just the boot files i think, i can still access all of the data okay by mounting it in linux. Ive tried a repair, but it says there is a problem while trying to repair. I have all my files and code for my PhD backed up, but there are just so many little bits and pieces in my linux installation that would take so long replace. I have a spare HDD, but GParted says its only 232Gb and the drive i want to clone is 238Gb. Am i right in thinking that wont work? This is why i was asking whether i could get away with cloning just the one partition, because i dont need the windows one in the clone..

Comment: If you back up just one partition and you lose the partition structure, you will have a big job recreating the partition environment for that partition to run. It is possible to produce a compressed image, such as in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/52264/409801), but make sure you (1) read all the caveats and (2) **always** add `-o sync` to the `dd` run string (if you don't, a disc error will make the image almost useless). You could also look at the drive-copying software on a bootable utilities disc, such as [Hiren's BootCD](https://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd).